# In unity 3d should i use in adventure game with point and click style or just walking using keys?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Today now i'm using the keys wsad to move my ThirdPersonCharacter around.
But since i'm doing an adventure game or more a quest game i wonder if i should make somehow a point and click style ?

The game i want to do is like the old school adventure games where you click on items and select what to do with them look/take/use. And since i'm doing it in 3d i wonder how should i make the game style ?

Another thing i didn't find any tutorials how ot make the point and click and also how to make the items for example if i put a cube on the space ship how do i make that if i use will click on it it will display a small options icons like look/take/use.

Another sub question is first time the character was when i moved it to the spaceship it was walking through it so i added a Mesh Collider to the space ship. Is that right to add a Mesh Collider ? Now it seems to be working i just wonder if it's right.

A screenshots of the game scene before added the collider. And scene3 after adding the collider:

[image: Scene1]

[image: Scene2]

[image: Scene3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, this decision is left up to you. We cannot answer that for you. However, there are some pros and cons of using either.

For point and click, there is basic code for doing this but there are so many parameters to take into account. Although you may want to go from point A to B, the code must be functional where you can avoid obstacles, walk on the ground, rotate the character accordingly, respond to other stimuli in the environment, etc. You can start with a simple:

```
Vector3 end;
float distance, scalarLerp;
Transform player;
LayerMask layer;
RaycastHit touch;

void Update(){
  if(Input.GetButtonDown(0)){
     Physics.Raycast(ScreenPointToRay(Input.MousePosition), distance, out touch, layer);
     start = player.position;
     end = touch.point;
}

  player.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.position, end, Time.deltaTime * scalarLerp);

}
```

This code is simple and you will realise the problems with point and click.

You could remain with the Third Person Controller but that is left up to you.